# Adding a string to all keys in dictionary (Python)

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I'm new to Python and Pyspark and I'm practicing TF-IDF.
I split all words from sentences in the txt file, removed punctuations, removed words that are in the stop-words list, and saved them as a dictionary with code snippet below.

```
x = text_file.flatmap(lambda line: str_clean(line).split()    
x = x.filter(lambda word: word not in stopwords    
x = x.reduceByKey(lambda a,b: a+b)    
x = x.collectAsMap()
```

I have 10 different txt files for this same process. And I'd like to add a string like `"@d1"` to keys in dictionary so that I can indicate that the key is from document 1.

How can I add `"@d1"` to all keys in the dictionary?

Essentially my dictionary is in the form:

```
{'word1': 1, 'word2': 1, 'word3': 2, ....}
```

And I would like it to be:

```
{'word1@d1': 1, 'word2@d1': 1, 'word3@d1': 2, ...}
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try a [dictionary comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#):

```
{k+'@d1': v for k, v in d.items()}
```

In Python 3.6+, you can use f-strings:

```
{f'{k}@d1': v for k, v in d.items()}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `dict` constructor to rebuild the dict, appending file number to the end of each key:

```
>>> d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> file_number = 1
>>> dict(("{}@{}".format(k,file_number),v) for k,v in d.items())
>>> {'a@1': 1, 'b@1': 2}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a list of dict that looks like below
[image]

```
def prefix_key_dict(prefix,test_dict):
   res = {prefix + str(key).lower(): val for key, val in test_dict.items()}
   return res

temp_prefix = 'column_'
transformed_dict = [prefix_dict(temp_prefix,each) for each in table_col_list]
```

and the transformed json looks like below
[image]